# Problem with two-argument column type in array package

Tags: tables

I'm trying to define common column types for math mode and fixed-width paragraph columns with pre-defined alignment.

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%
\newcolumntype{m}[1]{>{$}#1<{$}}
\newcolumntype{M}[2]{>{$}#1{#2}<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| mc | MC{3em} |}
  x^2 & x^2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The problems arise with the last two column types which should allow me to switch math mode on any of the default other column types. So `mc` takes `c` as argument, and uses it switching to math mode using `>{$}` and `<{$}`.

This works well for `mc` (try removing the second column) but not for `MC`. The mechanism should be the same, but now I take two arguments, the second being the paragraph width, and then pass it to `C`, `L` or `R` (or the original `p`, by the way).

However, the above code gives me error messages I cannot understand. It works if I embrace `C`, `L` or `R` with braces, as in `M{C}{3em}`. This surprises me because I supposed the rules were as in arguments to TeX macros, *i.e.* since `C` is a single token, it should be grabbed as the first argument. This works for `mc`, as it turns out, so the surprise is even bigger.

**EDIT**: It also works with `p` columns, *i.e.* writing `Mp{3em}` as column specifier works as expected, so the problem is related to the nesting of the two custom column specifiers.

So why doesn't it work as (I) expected? and can it be fixed to work in some way? Besides the workaround of using braces, that is.

P.S. I know many packages provide similar features (*e.g.* `mdwtab`), but I was trying to make it work myself.

Comment: `m` column type is already defined by the `array` package. for two letters column types see the package `mdwtab`.

Comment: I know about `mdwtab`, I mentioned it in the question as well. I know about `m` in `array` but I'm redefining it with another meaning and as you can see from the MWE it works well.

Comment: redefined `m` is not good idea. you never know when you will need its original meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to over-ride `m` but that is not the cause of the error. `array` package column types are expanded "by hand" to the underlying array package columns, and the expansion order isn't exactly the same as you would get from TeX macro expansion. Your preamble actually expands to

```
| >{$}c<{$} | >{$}>{\centering \arraybackslash }<{$}p{3em} |
```

where you can see the `<{$}` has been inserted too early, leading to the error given.

If you declare the columns in a different order:

```
\newcolumntype{M}[2]{>{$}#1{#2}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%
\newcolumntype{m}[1]{>{$}#1<{$}}
```

then the preamble expands to

```
| >{$}c<{$} | >{$}>{\centering \arraybackslash }p{3em}<{$} |
```

as intended.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use $ itself as a character for custom column types? So I wouldn’t need to override “m”

Comment: @gigabytes yes.

Comment: Good! I’ll use that then